# Arguments error while calling function

Tags: ruby

I am getting `ArgumentError in ArticlesController#scrape` on `def extract_Articles(source_url:, source_type:, source_key:)`

I am extracting the list of articles from different sources, and returning it back to my controller function.

```
class ArticleController

  def Scrape
      @get_Articles = Source.new
      articles = @get_Articles.get_Articles
      ...
  end
end

class Source
  def get_Articles
    @articles = Array.new
    @articles = extract_Articles('url1','rss',nil)
    @articles = extract_Articles('url2','rss',nil)
    @articles = extract_Articles('url3','rss',nil)
    @articles = extract_Articles('url4','json','some-value')

  end  
  def extract_Articles(soruce_url:, url_type:, source_key:)
    ...
  end
end
```

Could somebody let me know of this problem? Surprisingly I am not sure why this is not working actually!

Comment: Small point, ruby method naming is typically all lower case. Underscores are used instead of CamelCase.

Comment: I think we might need some more information, the routes for ArticleController would be helpful, as well as the log when this error is being called. This gives us a much better chance to answer appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your method is defined to use named arguments, but you try to call it with positional ones.

Either define it with positional arguments:

```
def extract_Articles(soruce_url, url_type, source_key)
  # ...
end
```

Or invoke it with named ones:

```
@articles = extract_Articles(soruce_url: 'url1', url_type: 'rss', source_key: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

the method arguments should be variables, and you also can set the default value for arguments.

```
def extract_Articles(soruce_url, url_type, source_key=nil)
    ...
end

@articles = extract_Articles('url1','rss')
@articles = extract_Articles('url4','json','some-value')
```

You can get more detail info from [here](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_methods.html)

Answer (score 2):

Method arguments cannot be symbols they need to be variables so that when function is called by passing values those variables will have that value.

Okay I have read about keyword params, so here is my updated answer

you need to pass params like this

```
@articles = extract_Articles(soruce_url: 'url1',url_type: 'rss',source_key:nil)
```

Comment: I would suggest you to read about [keyword arguments](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments).

Comment: Thanks I surely didn't know that